# Slow SSH keystroke latency over wifi, but loading the network improves it temporarily

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ssh, performance

I have this behavior I see sometimes with the new router I've installed in my house.

an SSH connection to a LAN Linux server is sluggish and slow, but if I run an `iperf` test between the machines, the connection is snappy again.

`iperf` also reports an adequate speed of >50Mbps (nowhere near the reported link speed of 144Mbit on the laptop, but whatever) and ping is a fairly consistent 1.5ms.

So it seems like some overly aggressive power-saving or other scheme is interfering.

How could I go about debugging this?

Comment: What does `top` look like when you are connected to the server? Can you take a Wireshark/tcpdump (preferably from client and server) which captures the slowness and upload it somewhere?

Comment: good tip on wireshark. The issue has completely disappeared today. No doubt it will return another time.